Running npm run dev is giving error how do i fix?
I used vite to generate frontend template. The package.json is in the frontend directory and contains dev but i'm getting this error. the project is django and react. i'm using a python VE the backend runs with no issues. i installed the dependencies for react to the env so i don't know :


{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.34.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}



error:


(env) PS C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Projects\API-test\Django&React FS\frontend> npm run dev

> frontend@0.0.0 dev
> vite

'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Projects\API-test\vite\bin\vite.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v20.12.1
(env) PS C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Projects\API-test\Django&React FS\frontend> 




By the error logs you have provided it seems that you have a couple of issues,
The first one is a misconfiguration of your package.json, specifically:
'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
However, at first glance I don't see any apparent issues with your package.json.
The second issue which is more likely to be the problem is:
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Abdul\Documents\Personal Projects\API-test\vite\bin\vite.js'

This indicates that the Vite package is either not installed or there is a path issue where node.js cannot find the 'vite.js' file.
So, to resolve this I suggest you reinstall vite to ensure its installed correctly:
npm install vite --save-dev

Then, make sure your command line is open in your frontend directory and run:
npm cache clean --force
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

After that, you can try to run npm run dev again.
Hope that helps.
**
EDIT:
So, as mentioned in the comment if you are unable to run rm -rf node_modules, then you are most likely not running the commands in the correct directory or you have installed node in the wrong directory. Make sure that your directory structure looks like this:
frontend/
 |-- node_modules/
 |-- components/
 |-- pages/
    |-- _app.js
 |-- public/

And, when you run the commands you need to be in the frontend directory. It might look something like this:
MyComputer-MBP:frontend MyUsername$

If you don't see frontend, you have to run the appropriate cd commands to access the directory.

it wont let me do 2 and 3rd last commands

Which commands are you not able to run exactly? and can you share what errors you get when you run them?

For “npm cache clean —force” it says using force isnt allowed. And for rm -rf node modules” it says rf cant be found.

Ok that gives me a clue into what your issue is, you are most likely not in the right directory when running these commands or you have installed node in the wrong directory. I will elaborate on my answer, so you can check after "EDIT" to see the update.

i figured it out: for some reason the bin file in NODE_MODULES was named ".bin". i just had to remove the full stop. thanks for you help.

No worries @Awm, happy to help and I'm glad your issue is resolved. However, I don't mean to be negative, but I have to suggest against removing the dot from .bin in node_modules. This directory is standard and renaming it can lead to unexpected behaviour when running scripts or installing new packages. It's best to keep this directory as it is to ensure your development environment remains stable and predictable.

But then npm run dev doesnt work? The error showed a path wasnt found that path has bin not .bin

Having the dot in the .bin directory within the node_modules is unlikely to be the cause of the error you're encountering with running npm run dev.  Try renaming it as was with the dot ".bin" and then run npm commands as provided in my answer. If you still get an error, it would help if you could add a screenshot of your terminal with the error and a screenshot of your directory structure.

I did what you said and i get the same initial error. My directories mirriw what you say. I’ve done it all in the correct directory. I can use node -v which comesback correctly with the version.

You can install React and vite either globally or locally in your project using npm or yarn.

To install React globally: npm install -g react
To install React locally in your project: npm install react
To install Vite globally: npm install -g vite
To install Vite locally in your project: npm install vite

After installing React and Vite, try running npm run dev again. If you've installed them locally, ensure that the paths to their binaries are correctly configured in your project's package.json file.

how do i "ensure that the paths to their binaries are correctly configured in your project's package.json file."? i dont see anywhere to do that in the json file
